# Copying large amounts of code from Xcode to Emacs loses code

Tags: xcode, emacs, copy-paste

I like working in Xcode and not Emacs, but we have to use Emacs for our assignments.

It seems whenever I try copying large amounts of code over from Xcode to Emacs that it just "gives up" after a certain point and leaves off a large amount of text, even leaving some text out sporadically up to 3 or 4 lines above where it cut off.

Is this an issue with braces, spacing, any ideas? Can it simply not copy over that much data at once? (I have 414 lines of code at the moment.)

I'm looking to solve the heart of the problem here, not just maneuvering around it. I can get around it by chunking up the data and doing multiple copy/pastes.

Comment: Why not just save the source file from within Xcode and then open it in emacs ?

Comment: I tried doing that but I can't transfer files from my computer to our server.

Comment: @PandamPleb (I did not downvote you) Maybe it is because your question is not really a programming issue? You may have better luck if you try other SO sister sites like superuser or appleexchange

Comment: You say you can't transfer files from your computer to your server. Does that mean you are running emacs on the server through some terminal program?  The terminal program could be the cause of the lossage in this case.  Also, if you are pasting into a terminal window, the terminal will basically send those characters to Emacs as if they were typed. This could have unexpected results if there are any control characters, or Emacs has any auto- behaviour enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below, which provides a command `ttypaste-mode` which you can run just before "pasting" code into your Emacs running inside a terminal emulator.  It tries to work around the usual problems linked to going through a terminal emulator.  To exit this mode, hit the ESC key.

```lisp
(defvar ttypaste-mode nil)
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(ttypaste-mode " Paste"))

;; A loop reading `read-event' is several times faster than using a kind
;; of minor mode with a keymap catching all character events; probably because
;; it avoids going through a lot of extra code, like pre-command-hook,
;; post-command-hook, ...
(defun ttypaste-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (current-buffer))
        (ttypaste-mode t))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (let ((stay t)
            (text (current-buffer)))
        (redisplay)
        (while stay
          (let ((char (or (let ((inhibit-redisplay t)) (read-event nil t 0.1))
                          (with-current-buffer buf
                            (insert-buffer-substring text))
                          (erase-buffer)
                          (redisplay)
                          (read-event nil t))))
            (cond
             ((or (not (characterp char))
                  (and (eq char ?\e) (sit-for 0.1 'nodisp)))
              (setq stay nil))
             ((eq char ?\r) (insert ?\n))
             (t (insert char)))))
        (insert-buffer-substring text)))))
```